# How to fill divs with different color?

Tags: html, css, visible

I am creating grid with multiple divs and each div has different color. But the following code display all divs in one gray color. How can I change the color of divs?

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}


.Rect{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;

}

.Rect1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: -300px;
}

.Rect2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -600px;
}

.Rect3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -900px;
}

#rectYellow{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1125px;
  left: 100px;
}

#rectGreen{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1125px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectBlue{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1200px;
  left: 0px;
}

#rectWhite{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: White;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1425px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectOrange{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: Orange;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1275px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <div id=container>
    
    <!--1th row -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div id="rectBlue"></div><!--BLUE -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <!--2th row -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectYellow"></div><!--YELLOW -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectOrange"></div><!--ORANGE -->
    <!--3th row -->
    <div id="rectWhite"></div><!--WHITE -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <div id="rectGreen"></div><!--GREEN -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <!--4th row -->
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div> 
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    </div>
```

I'm stuck about what happened, apologies for the block of code. I couldn't use fiddle.

Comment: Working fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/0a8adkt0/ and @Paulie_D there is a fiddle in question that you'll see if you edit it but I'm not sure how should I edit that :(

Comment: There should be white,yellow,blue,green and orange shapes in there as well. they're named rectColor respectively. On my screen there is just a blank space where they should be.

Comment: The only reason that they vanished because you didn't gave the appropriate top and left absolute position, That's what caused the elements to move out of document.

Answer (score 0):

Your `top` calculations were off. I've updated them ( switched the white to pink just for the demo ) so that they line up in the snippet.

That being said, I'm unsure of what the end result is supposed to be. It might be easier to use `position:absolute;` and define a specific dimension for the container than calculate each element's `relative` position. Or make each element `display: inline-block;` and let them wrap naturally.

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}


.Rect{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;

}

.Rect1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: -300px;
}

.Rect2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -600px;
}

.Rect3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -900px;
}

#rectYellow{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 100px;
}

#rectGreen{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -600px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectBlue{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#rectWhite{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -600px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectOrange{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: Orange;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    
    <!--1th row -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div id="rectBlue"></div><!--BLUE -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <!--2th row -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectYellow"></div><!--YELLOW -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectOrange"></div><!--ORANGE -->
    <!--3th row -->
    <div id="rectWhite"></div><!--WHITE -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <div id="rectGreen"></div><!--GREEN -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <!--4th row -->
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div> 
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid `top` positions in your code. It should be like this:

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}


.Rect{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;

}

.Rect1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: -300px;
}

.Rect2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -600px;
}

.Rect3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -900px;
}

#rectYellow{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 100px;
}

#rectGreen{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -600px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectBlue{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#rectWhite{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: White;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1425px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectOrange{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: Orange;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    
    <!--1th row -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div id="rectBlue"></div><!--BLUE -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <!--2th row -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectYellow"></div><!--YELLOW -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectOrange"></div><!--ORANGE -->
    <!--3th row -->
    <div id="rectWhite"></div><!--WHITE -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <div id="rectGreen"></div><!--GREEN -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <!--4th row -->
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div> 
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that it vanished because you didn't gave the appropriate `top` and `left` `absolute position`, That's what caused the elements to move out of document. But now its fixed and working....

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}


.Rect{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;

}

.Rect1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: -300px;
}

.Rect2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: -600px;
}

.Rect3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -900px;
}

#rectYellow{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: 100px;
}

#rectGreen{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -600px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectBlue{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: 200px;
}

#rectWhite{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -526px;
  left: 100px;
}

#rectOrange{
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: Orange;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -375px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    
    <!--1th row -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <div id="rectBlue"></div><!--BLUE -->
    <div class="Rect"></div>
    <!--2th row -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectYellow"></div><!--YELLOW -->
    <div class="Rect1"></div>
    <div id="rectOrange"></div><!--ORANGE -->
    <!--3th row -->
    <div id="rectWhite"></div><!--WHITE -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <div id="rectGreen"></div><!--GREEN -->
    <div class="Rect2"></div>
    <!--4th row -->
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div> 
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    <div class="Rect3"></div>
    </div>
```